# crontab sometimes doesnt work

Tags: cron

I am trying to execute a script via crontab but some scripts work, while other do not. Why does this happen?

```
username@here> crontab -l
00 13 * * * csh -c /home/apps/bin/jobnumberone.pl
00 18 * * * csh_cmd /home/apps/bin/forcestartjob.pl job_a
5 22 * * 1-5 csh_cmd /home/apps/bin/forcestartjob.pl job_b
5 1 * * 1-5 /home/apps/bin/forcestartjob.pl job_c
5 1 * * 1-5 /home/apps/test/write_to_file.sh
```

My `write_to_file.sh` simply prints the current time to a file `test1.txt`. When I check `test1.txt`, the correct time stamp is shown, which suggests that I do have permission to modify the crontab and at least one of the crontab events are being executed at the correct time. (Yes, I do have the extra line at the end of the crontab file. )

Additionally, I can directly run `/home/apps/bin/forcestartjob.pl job_c` , but when I try to run it from the crontab it does not execute. The permissions for execute seem to be valid:

```
username@here> ls -l "/home/apps/bin/forcestartjob.pl"
-rwxr-xr-x   1 name     name     Jan 20 08:27 /home/apps/bin/forcestartjob.pl
```

Comment: Am I reading this incorrectly or are you using the C shell to run Perl scripts?

Comment: Yes. That is correct @muru

Comment: And which of these jobs are affected?

Comment: `5 1 * * 1-5 /home/apps/bin/forcestartjob.pl job_c`

Comment: Only that one? Does it produce any output that you can log to a file by redirection?

Comment: That one and `5 22 * * 1-5 csh_cmd /home/apps/bin/forcestartjob.pl job_b`. It will log something if executed. But the logs show nothing, which is why I think they're not executing. However, if I directly run (not through crontab) I get the proper execution.

Comment: Not a solution but adding `MAILTO="username"` to crontab will send email when runs (so you can tell if running or not) also, if there a problem I think it gives a little detail in the email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Wrap the entire command in double quotes.

Hint: Check the `mail` because it will show you a little log. It will be in a directory like `/var/mail`. You can use `cat /var/mail/username` to display all the messages.

Explanation: My issue was that my script required a parameter passed in as an argument in the command. crontab interprets everything separated by a space as a separate object so my command had an error executing. Using double quotes will let the crontab execute the whole thing as one command.

ex:

- Original =

  `csh -c /home/apps/bin/forcestartjob.pl job_b`
- Correct =

  `csh -c "/home/apps/bin/forcestartjob.pl job_b"`

Took me a long time to find this silly issue, but hopefully this helps somebody else in the future.